# Sticky product summary on Woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to make the product summary on the Woocommerce single product page sticky. I have

```
.summary.entry-summary{
 position:sticky;
 top:100px
}
```

And this work, but the summary now sticks even when you have reached the produt tabs and goes on top of these. How can I make the summary stop being sticky when it reaches the product tab section?